# Get index of array element faster than O(n)

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance, indexing

Given I have a HUGE array, and a value from it. I want to get index of the value in array. Is there any other way, rather then call `Array#index` to get it? The problem comes from the need of keeping really huge array and calling `Array#index` enormous amount of times.

After a couple of tries I found that *caching* indexes inside elements by storing structs with `(value, index)` fields instead of the value itself gives a huge step in performance (20x times win).

Still I wonder if there's a more convenient way of finding index of en element without caching (or there's a good caching technique that will boost up the performance).

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Convert the array into a hash. Then look for the key.

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
hash = Hash[array.map.with_index.to_a]    # => {"a"=>0, "b"=>1, "c"=>2}
hash['b'] # => 1
```

Comment: fastest if the array is very long

Comment: Depending on your use case this could be problematic if there are duplicate values.

The method described above will return the equivalent or #rindex(last occurrence of value)    

To get #index equivalent results, meaning the hash returning the first index of the value you'd need to do something along the lines of reversing the array before creating the hash then subtracting the returned index value from the total length of the initial array - 1.   

#  (array.length - 1 ) - hash['b']

Comment: Doesn't the conversion into a hash take O(n) time? I suppose if it's going to be used more than once, then hash conversion will be more performant. but for single usage, is it no different then iterating through the array?

Comment: Yes, and probably worse for single use if it really matters as hash calculation won't short-circuit as quickly as a comparison.

Comment: If you have duplicate elements, @hololeap's answer is more complete.

Answer (score 199):

Why not use index or rindex?

```
array = %w( a b c d e)
# get FIRST index of element searched
puts array.index('a')
# get LAST index of element searched
puts array.rindex('a')
```

> index: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-index
>
> rindex: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-rindex

Comment: This is exactly what the OP said they DIDN'T want, due to the large size of their array. Array#index is O(n) and doing that multiple times will kill on performance. Hash lookup is O(1).

Comment: @tim, well i can't remember at the time of my answer that THIS was the **same** question, maybe the OP revised the question later on, which would invalidate this answer.

Comment: Would it not say that it had been edited at a specific time then?

Comment: Hehe, yeah thats true. Well me and another 30 people were reading over it then. I guess :/

Answer (score 11):

Other answers don't take into account the possibility of an entry listed multiple times in an array. This will return a hash where each key is a unique object in the array and each value is an array of indices that corresponds to where the object lives:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]
=> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]

indices = a.each_with_index.inject(Hash.new { Array.new }) do |hash, (obj, i)| 
    hash[obj] += [i]
    hash
end
=> { 1 => [0, 3], 2 => [1, 4], 3 => [2, 5], 4 => [6] }
```

This allows for a quick search for duplicate entries:

```
indices.select { |k, v| v.size > 1 }
=> { 1 => [0, 3], 2 => [1, 4], 3 => [2, 5] }
```

Comment: This is a more complete answer than @sawa's.

Answer (score 6):

Is there a good reason not to use a hash? Lookups are `O(1)` vs. `O(n)` for the array.

Comment: The point is -- I'm calling `#keys` on hash, which returns an array I am using. Still, I might think over my architecture as well...

Answer (score 3):

If it's a **sorted** array you could use a Binary search algorithm (`O(log n)`). For example, extending the Array-class with this functionality:

```
class Array
  def b_search(e, l = 0, u = length - 1)
    return if lower_index > upper_index

    midpoint_index = (lower_index + upper_index) / 2
    return midpoint_index if self[midpoint_index] == value

    if value < self[midpoint_index]
      b_search(value, lower_index, upper_index - 1)
    else
      b_search(value, lower_index + 1, upper_index)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It actually isn't that hard to read. First part, return if lower bound is bigger than upper bound (the recursion has filed). second part checks if we need the left side or right side by comparing the midpoint m with the value at that point to e. if we don't have the answer we want, we recurse.

Comment: I think it do better to the ego of people downvoting rather than editing.

Answer (score 3):

If your array has a natural order use binary search.

Use binary search.

Binary search has `O(log n)` access time.

Here are the steps on how to use binary search,

- What is the ordering of you array? For example, is it sorted by name?
- Use `bsearch` to find elements or indices

Code example

```
# assume array is sorted by name!

array.bsearch { |each| "Jamie" <=> each.name } # returns element
(0..array.size).bsearch { |n| "Jamie" <=> array[n].name } # returns index
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking a combination of @sawa's answer and the comment listed there you could implement a "quick" index and rindex on the array class.

```
class Array
  def quick_index el
    hash = Hash[self.map.with_index.to_a]
    hash[el]
  end

  def quick_rindex el
    hash = Hash[self.reverse.map.with_index.to_a]
    array.length - 1 - hash[el]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> Still I wonder if there's a more convenient way of finding index of en element without caching (or there's a good caching technique that will boost up the performance).

You can use binary search (if your array is ordered *and* the values you store in the array are comparable in some way). For that to work you need to be able to tell the binary search whether it should be looking "to the left" or "to the right" of the current element. But I believe there is nothing wrong with storing the `index` at insertion time and then using it if you are getting the element from the same array.