# Get array index based on child hash value

Tags: ruby

Say I have this:

```
[
  {
             :id => 34,
    :votes_count => 3
  },
  {
             :id => 2,
    :votes_count => 0
  },
]
```

How do I get the index based on `id`? What I want to do is return `0` when I search for `id: 34`, and `1` when I search for `id: 2`. What is the most efficient way?

Comment: Yes, it seems like this would be a better job for a real database system. Are you building a web app? Could you be using Rails?

Comment: @Eric it is to assign a rank, and get that rank based on the `:id`.

Comment: You're both correct, I'm leaving out much of the system for brevity, and I am using Rails. This is actually an ActiveRecord result set.

Comment: @Zenph If you are using Rails, then why not use [the normal ActiveRecord query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)? I suspect there is a reasonable way to do it.

Comment: @jtbandes I would, but I've not found a reasonable way. I will have to cache these ranks, because at the minute I am fetching data from a table `ordered by votes desc` (which is the result set above). Essentially I will be calling `Thing.find(123).rank # => 2`

Comment: @jtbandes thinking about it, this sounds like a good use case for redis sorted sets.

Comment: Check this solution, it works for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6242393/1770571

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can pass a block to `#index`:

```
array.index {|h| h[:id] == 34 } # => 0
```

Comment: I love answers that are straight to the point, and exactly what you need. Thanks!

Comment: This was really handy after converting an Activerecord collection to an array then wanting to still find specific records by the model hash value.