# How Get Index If Object In Array Contains Desired Value in Ruby

Tags: ruby

So this is an array I get from somewhere and I wanted to get the index of the object that contains "text" => "Assets". How can i do that in Ruby?

Example

```
[{
                     "class" => "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView",
                       "tag" => nil,
               "description" => "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{b777d8c V.ED..... ........ 0,39-355,168 #7f0e007f app:id/textview_sectiontitle}",
                        "id" => "textview_sectiontitle",
                      "text" => "Assets",
                   "visible" => true,
                      "rect" => {
              "height" => 129,
               "width" => 355,
                   "y" => 2088,
                   "x" => 80,
            "center_x" => 257,
            "center_y" => 2152
        },
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil
    },
    {
                     "class" => "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton",
                       "tag" => nil,
               "description" => "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton{ae57704 VFED..C.. ........ 1056,0-1280,208 #7f0e0109 app:id/imagebutton_amount}",
                        "id" => "imagebutton_amount",
                   "visible" => true,
                      "rect" => {
              "height" => 208,
               "width" => 224,
                   "y" => 2049,
                   "x" => 1136,
            "center_x" => 1248,
            "center_y" => 2153
        },
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil
    }]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get array index based on child hash value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404618/get-array-index-based-on-child-hash-value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one

```
arr.index { |item| item["text"] == "Assets" }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try your answer.

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)