# Im trying to delete a group of items inside an array in between two points, literally matching the giving points

Tags: ruby

Let's say that u have a given array and the idea is to get rid of everything in between these two poins: **'a'** and **'e'**, The result will be a new array but starting with **'a'** like this ex:

```
arr = %w(a b c d e f j k)
```

and the outcome will be:

```
arr['a', 'f', 'j, 'k']
```

How  would u make the check-function for this challenge?

Comment: Your question is not clear..

Comment: @ArupRakshit still not clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the array index of the first element you want to count:

```
 start = array.index('a')
```

Get the array index of the last elementoyou want to count:

```
 end = array.rindex('e')
```

Then split the array inside those elements:

```
 array = %w(a b c d e f j k)[start, end]
```

That should work.

Reference:
[Get index of array element faster than O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242311/quickly-get-index-of-array-element-in-ruby)