# Finding indices of element in array ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

How can you find the indices of all elements in an array that has a particular value in ruby?
I.e. if you have an array [2,3,52,2,4,1,2], is there an easier way than to use loops, to get the indices of all 2 in the array? So the answer would be something like [0,3,6], if I am looking for 2. 
The answer in 
[Get index of array element faster than O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242311/quickly-get-index-of-array-element-in-ruby)
gives the solution if I want to find just one instance of the given element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a
# => [2, 3, 52, 2, 4, 1, 2]
b = []
# => []
a.each_with_index{|i, ind| b << ind if i == 2}
# => [2, 3, 52, 2, 4, 1, 2]
```

Comment: This wont get you the output as per your requirements. Luka's or Rick's answers are what you might be looking for.

Comment: Have you checked array b...? I forgot to paste that output.. check once by your own

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use this:

```
a = [2, 3, 52, 2, 4, 1, 2]

b = a.map.with_index{|k, i| i if k == 2}.compact
b
# => [0,3,6]
```

Or if you wanna to modify a variable so modify version.

```
a = [2, 3, 52, 2, 4, 1, 2]
a.map!.with_index{|k, i| i if k == 2}.compact!
a
# => [0,3,6]
```

Comment: Since it is `b` you are building, why use `map`? You are mapping `a` to an array that you don't use. Isn't `a.each_with_index` more direct?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I modify usage of map in this case. You have right, i use it "uncorrect" in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one,

```
arr = [2,3,52,2,4,1,2]
    output = []
    arr.each_with_index do |v,i|
       if v == 2
         output << i
       end
    end

puts output #=> [0, 3, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I got a shortened version of this which worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

```
a.each_with_object([]).find_all {|i, index| i == 2}.map {|i, index| index }
```

I feel like there's still a shortcut though.

Another option might be :

```
a.each_with_object([]).with_index {|(i, result), index| result << index if i == 2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [2,3,52,2,4,1,2]

a.each_index.select { |i| a[i]== 2 }
  #=> [0, 3, 6]
```