# How to get the Index of a specific item in Multidimensional (nested) Arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
ary=[ [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]],
      [[0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5]],
      [[0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8]] ]
```

I am trying to find the index in the "main" array that contains an array with `[0, 4]` in it, which is `1`.

I've been working with the idea like this:

```
ary.each_index.select{|index| #(return index if [0,4] matches) }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
ary.find_index { |arr| arr.include?([0, 4]) }
```

Comment: i can't believe i didn't think of this before haha

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the following.

[Find indices of elements that match a given condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659696/find-indices-of-elements-that-match-a-given-condition)

[Get index of array element faster than O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242311/get-index-of-array-element-faster-than-on)

http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/find_index

Comment: It's not really an answer if you don't demonstrate how it works. Link-only answers are considered low quality.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following.

```
ary.find_index { |arr| arr.index([0, 4]) }
```